# CFNumber to int or NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsnumber

I am parsing a JSON string using NSJSONSerialzation, and then casting it into a NSDictionary to work with key value pairs. Some of the values in the JSON string were sent as integers by the server, however, the NSDictionary represents them as a CFNumber e.g.

```
<CFNumber 0xa581270 [0x1d7b4d8]>{value = +0, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
```

How could I convert this neatly into an int or NSNumber ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can just cast it because of [toll-free bridging](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002401-767858)

```
NSNumber *num = (NSNumber *)cfnum;
```

if ARC enabled

```
NSNumber *num = (__bridge NSNumber *)cfnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber and CFNumberRef are toll free bridged, which means to convert one to the other all you have to do is cast whichever one you have to the type you want.  In ARC code to convert a CFNumberRef to an NSNumber use (__bridge NSNumber*) theCFNumberRef.